# How to disable parent ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML structure with `ng-click`:

```
<div ng-click="parent()">
  <div ng-click="d"></div>
</div>
```

How I can disable outside `ng-click="parent()"` if I do `ng-click="d"`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the `stopPropagation` method on the angular `$event` object:

```
<div ng-click="parent()">
  <div ng-click="d(); $event.stopPropagation();"></div>
</div>
```

Or pass the `$event` object as an argument of the `ng-click` method, and call `stopPropagation` in the method:

```
<div ng-click="parent()">
  <div ng-click="d($event)"></div>
</div>
```

In `d`:

```
$scope.d = function (event) {
    // ...
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add **$event.stopPropagation();** on the child ng-click. It will prevent the parent ng-click.

Example:

```
<div ng-click="parent();">
  <div ng-click="child(); $event.stopPropagation();">
  </div>
</div>
```